# How to turn off the dark mode on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, dark-mode

I recently enabled the new dark mode on stack overflow. However, I'm not too comfortable using it in the site in that look. Is there any way I can turn it off?

Comment: This got migrated, so I can't dupe it but it is the answer https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396014/how-do-i-change-back-to-the-non-dark-light-theme

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/30/introducing-dark-mode-for-stack-overflow/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current and then click "Light".